# Manage event for recent app hardware button

Tags: android, events

I want to handle hardware button for recent application button. I have tried with `onUserLeaveHint()` method, but it will call for both home button and recent app button. But, I don't want to override home button event. Any help appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Please add comment for down voting

Answer (score 0):

You have to `override` first `onKeyDown` then write your code like below:-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        System.out.println("KEYCODE_HOME");
        showDialog("'HOME'");
        return true;
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        System.out.println("KEYCODE_BACK");
        showDialog("'BACK'");
        return true;
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)) {
        System.out.println("KEYCODE_MENU");
        showDialog("'MENU'");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[You can read this link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/06/02/override-hardware-home-button-android-listen-home-button-click-android/)

Comment: This is not working with a higher version. I have tried this solution.

Comment: what do you means by higher version?

Comment: Above 5.0. i have tested it on 7.0